# Identification of a Kakadu bird

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

This species of bird was spotted in Kakadu National Park, NT, Australia. It looks a bit like a [lemon-bellied fly catcher](http://www.bushpea.com/bd/ph/kay/mi/lemon-bellied%20flycatcher%2001.jpg), but I think my bird here is a tad bigger than the fly catcher, but I am unsure.

I was hoping one of the more ecologically proficient people here could help me out.

[image: bird]

<sub>Note: This is the 3<sup>rd</sup> related question on this topic, so feel free to close-vote-for-whatever-reason, but I am generating a photo album with all the birds I have spotted there (heaps!), and a few of them I can't identify with the limited resources I have.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is great bowerbird (*Chlamydera nuchalis*). It is much bigger than the mentioned flycatcher. I have seen both species and there is no room for confusion. Most of the pictures online are birds perched on the ground next to their "buildings", but I found a picture that should convince you.

[image: http://www.hbw.com/sites/default/files/styles/ibc_1k/public/ibc/p/grbb_5683_800.JPG?itok=4jIw2F75]

Notice:

-Stout bill

-Patterned wing coverts

-Marks on the undertail coverts

Comment: Thanks!! Lovely :-) Could you add the link of the picture if possible? In my sources the bower bird looks brownish, whilst in my photo and your image above it looks yellowish - or is that a male/female difference perhaps?

Comment: Here is my [resource](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj9kbqIqp7SAhXmdpoKHaxgCUQQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.environment.gov.au%2Fsystem%2Ffiles%2Fresources%2F0ee966d5-a8b0-4827-aa96-25f6cd9e9996%2Ffiles%2Fkakadu-np-bird-monitoring.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFj1qGBQPXYr0-2Su5bliMV7Z4Q0w&sig2=j42ON0kaSdxKJb0iJ8evcw) - page 3, left column middle image - it looks brownish, not yellowish

Comment: @AliceD It was edited out I do not know why. (The picture is in the second page).  http://www.hbw.com/ibc/species/great-bowerbird-chlamydera-nuchalis        I think that the yellow is a picture effect, look at the color of the branch...that also look yellow.